# Nginx Rule to Block Specific URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Need some help in writing a rule to block the following request

The url in question is:

```
www.somesite.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=downloader
```

I have tried the following, but this does not work

```
location ^~ catalogsearch/result/?q=downloader {
    deny all;
}
```

I "think" the because the ? question mark is included is treating the url as a query string??

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to block access through the parameter `q=downloader` only at URL www.somesite.com/catalogsearch/result/ :

```
error_page 418 = @blockAccess;

location /catalogsearch/result {
        if ($args ~* "q=downloader") {
                return 418;
        }
}

location @blockAccess {
        deny all;
}
```

> Add before `location /`

If you want to block the `q=downloader` parameter of all URL's, just put the code below before `location`:

```
error_page 418 = @blockAccess;

if ($args ~* "q=downloader") {
    return 418;
}

location @blockAccess {
    deny all;
}
```

If you want to block the www.somesite.com/catalogsearch/result/ :

```
error_page 418 = @blockAccess;

# Add before "location /"
location /catalogsearch/result {
        return 418;
}

location @blockAccess {
        deny all;
}
```

Comment: Hi Valdeir, your suggested answers provided a solution
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for saving the whole day

Comment: i want rule, if someone enter "/api/123" it should return 403, everything except "/api/"  location shoud return 403

Comment: @user3782114 `location = /api/123`